# Is there an R function equivalent to wrapping assignment with `()`?

Tags: printing, assign

I just discovered that running `(y <- 1:4)` prints the result in the console, but ...

```r
(y <- 1:4)
# [1] 1 2 3 4

library(dplyr) # for the pipe operator %>% 
y <- 1:4 %>% funct_parenthesis() # DOES IT EXIST ?
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` works

```r
library(dplyr) # for the pipe operator %>% 
y <- 1:4 %>% print
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```